# Ubuntu 12.04 apt directory corrupted

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-center

I have recently installed ubuntu 12.04 on my old HP dv6646us laptop. I was trying to install jdk7 (Java Development Kit 7) on it and tried many things. Long story short, I think I corrupted the `/var/cache/apt` directory. Software Center is now not working. I am running Windows Vista and Ubuntu 12.04 on this machine as dual boot.

Here is the output of an `ls -l` on the `/var/cache/apt` directory

```
jmk@ubuntu:/var/cache/apt$ ls -l
ls: cannot access srcpkgcache.bin: Input/output error
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar  6 21:57 archives
-????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? srcpkgcache.bin
```

As you can see srcpkgcache.bin is messed up. I am completely new to ubuntu and I did try this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but that did not work.

Is there anyway to get this fixed without re-installing ubuntu?

Comment: reason for the down vote would have been appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin` and `/var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin` files.It would be automatically created after running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install package-name` commands.

This is not the cause of your software-center not working problem.